# Is it possible to draw xticklabels on top of the xaxis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, alignment

I want to mark a specific x-axis position with a colored asterisk drawn on top of the x-axis.

I use an x-tick label as the marker (because I couldn't figure out if it is possible to place markers anywhere in the fig coords) at it's aligned properly but is drawn below the x-axis so it's partially covered.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.scatter([-1,1],[1,1])
ax.set_xticks([0],minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(['*'],minor=True,color='r',fontsize=20,verticalalignment='center')

plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), linewidth=3)

plt.show()
```

That's what it looks like right now:

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the output you have right now? The problem is not clear from your question

Comment: I want the asterisk to be above the axis. Right now, the axis covers part of the symbol, I want it to be the other way around. It's more obvious with a thicker axis though.

Comment: I got it now. Check my answer and let me know if this is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the coordinates of a scatter in a blended system (data coordinates for the y axis and axis coordinates for the x axis).
To then have the scatter marker above the spines set the `zorder` property of the scatter to something above 2.5.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.scatter([-1,1],[1,1])
ax.scatter(0,0, s=100, marker="*", color="red", 
           transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(), clip_on=False, zorder=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a really good solution to use different markers

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `zorder` parameter. By using `zorder = 0`, you basically define the order of stacking of the plot sequence. `0` would send the axis/frame in the background putting the asterisk over the axis line as desired. I increased the size of the asterisk to highlight it.

```
ax.scatter([-1,1],[1,1])
ax.set_xticks([0],minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(['*'],minor=True,color='r',fontsize=30,verticalalignment='center')

plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), linewidth=3, zorder=0)
```

Alternatively, you can also specify the `zorder` for both plotting commands but use a higher `zorder` for the asterisk

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['*'],minor=True,color='r',fontsize=30,verticalalignment='center', zorder=2)
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), linewidth=3, zorder=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed